# Is there any P2P private file storage?

Tags: backup, encryption, storage, dropbox, p2p

I would like to upload my private encrypted files to the cloud. However I don't want to rely on a company to do this, such as Dropbox. If I share it on a P2P network (such as using torrents) nobody would copy my files.

I am willing to copy other people's files if they do the same for me. Is there such a P2P network for private encrypted files?

Comment: If you're worried about sensitive data, I'd recommend truecrypt + dropbox or another established backup service with a reliability guarantee. P2P is **not** going to be reliable in any sense of the word. You can't depend upon the data to be there when you need it, which does defeat the purpose of a backup.

Comment: Personally, I go with truecrypt + dropbox as Darth Android suggest (with a local NAS serving as local backup).  If you are concerned about the reliability of one company, you could easily point multiple services towards your truecypt file.  You could for instance easily have dropbox and carbonite both backing up the truecrypt file.

Comment: Agree. They're not affordable. Encrypt with TrueCrypt and store in a old plain online storage

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two solutions that I know of that provide this:

- [Crashplan](http://www.crashplan.com/) – you can trade storage with your friends.
- [Buddybackup](http://www.buddybackup.com/) – ditto.

http://skeptu.com/p2p-backup-software keeps an updated list of such software.

Comment: Wuala does not offer P2P-storage-trading anymore. They abolished it 2 months ago. It is still extremely fast compared to other online backup solutions.

Comment: You should disclose your affiliation with a website or service you're promoting.

Comment: crashplan is getting out of the home and p2p markets in 2017-11, and the skeptu.com link no longer works

Answer (score 7):

[Freenet](http://freenetproject.org/) is the one project that springs to mind.

> Freenet is free software which lets you anonymously share files, browse and publish "freesites" (web sites accessible only through Freenet) and chat on forums, without fear of censorship. Freenet is decentralised to make it less vulnerable to attack, and if used in "darknet" mode, where users only connect to their friends, is very difficult to detect.

Otherwise there is a list of distributed file storage systems at http://www.infoanarchy.org/en/Distributed_file_storage

It appears that a number of the projects are dead though, MNet was last updated in 2005... not sure about any of the others.

Comment: I would expect that so long as you access the files you are storing on a semi-regular basis you could use that method to keep them "in the cloud" as it were.

Comment: I clicked every link, and Freenet is the only one running.

Answer (score 5):

We have also **BuddyBackup**

http://www.buddybackup.com/about/how-buddybackup-works.aspx

Also Microsoft's **Live Mesh** is similar, but limited to your machines and the central storage

http://www.techcrunchit.com/2008/07/21/live-mesh-rolls-out-p2p-storage/

As for research projects, we also have:

- Microsoft's **PAST** (2001-2010) http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/antr/PAST/
- National Tsing Hua University's **Malugo** (2009) http://ir.lib.nthu.edu.tw/handle/987654321/17890
- Nanyang Technological University's **CrowdStore** (2009-2012) http://sands.sce.ntu.edu.sg/p2pstorage/

Comment: Personally I'd say this fits the bill better than Freenet, as Freenet seems to be more about content distribution than storage.  +1 for a good find!

Comment: I would say that this is a better answer than my one so feel free to unaccept mine (if you can) and accept this.  I think you may have to wait a day or two before you can accept your own answer though...

Comment: ... I wouldn't trust Microsoft (Live Mesh) with my data even if it was the only online storage service.

Answer (score 2):

Some on [I2P](http://www.i2p2.de/) were playing around with [Tahoe-LAFS](https://tahoe-lafs.org/trac/tahoe-lafs), and there is a [plugin](http://flattr.com/thing/114330/Tahoe-lafs-I2P-1-8-1-released) for I2P.

Answer (score 2):

Check out another open source distributed p2p backup system - BitDust.

It is in testing stage at the moment and you can download and use the software.

The web site is http://bitdust.io

Short video preview about it: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qP0KeeO-zRY](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Kf2YKiS-yk)

Comment: Now my project is calling BitDust: http://bitdust.io

Answer (score -3):

You could perhaps try Quiknets.com (Windows/ IE). When you register there you get a Private Box, InBox, email, Workspaces, ability to make a folder to share with named others chat, etc. Under Extra Content, you can download some FCRLite encryption. That allows you to make "self extracting" encrypted files/folders. When the user enters a password (any password you choose and convey to him), even if he doesn't have the encryption program. Files are always stored as you send them and are encrypted under a password only you know. You can send to any email address, as well as transferring an encrypted object to any Quiknets member privately.

In addition, you can right-click any file/folder in Quiknets and "copy the link", and then use that url to make a "login link" to it in Netsso.com. From any PC, Netsso will then bring you direct to the file, including logging in your Quiknets credentials, when you simply double-click the link.

Comment: It looks like you're affiliated with this product. Please take a look at our [FAQ#promotion] to see what our rules are on self-promotion. You're required to disclose your affiliation with the product you are recommending. Be warned that if you continue to post low-quality answers promoting your own products that your account may be suspended.